# Embedded ActiveMQ Server within Tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat7, activemq-classic, tomcat8

I am trying to embed ActiveMQ Server within Tomcat 8 server.
For that I was following two tutorials available online.

https://isomorphic.atlassian.net/wiki/display/Main/Real-Time+Messaging+with+Tomcat+and+ActiveMQ

and

http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2010/12/20/integrating-activemq-tomcat-using-global-jndi

In first tutorial changes were made only in $TomcatHome/conf/context.xml. But in second tutorial it was recommended to modify context.xml, server.xml and activemq.xml.

I follows both the tutorial separately one by one, also tried to use these with "Tomcat 7". But looks like both are not working for me.

With these changes, tomcat server starts without any issue no error in log. But Embedded ActiveMQ BrokerService is not getting started with Tomcat. Nothing is there in startup log for BrokerService.

Means there is no effect of these configurations on Tomcat Serve, and startup log is same with or without these configuration.
Am I missing anything in configuration for Tomcat 7 or Tomcat 8?
Why new JNDI Resource TAGs in configuration files is not getting picked by Tomcat?

Guys please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at starting up ActiveMQ using the Spring XML bean configuration. Generally, you'll need/want to do some configuration of the broker and having the full XML is a simple way to manage that. I suggest looking at creating a simple war file that starts up a Spring beans.xml file. That file should just be the same contents as the conf/activemq.xml configuration. You then add all the JNDI resources as needed to point to the embedded broker.

Comment: Embedded-ActiveMQ in Tomcat can be used and shared by all the web applications deployed over Tomcat and even from outside Tomcat. But for Spring-Embedded ActiveMQ  access will be limited only to that Spring-Application. Other applications will not we used that Spring-Embedded ActiveMQ to send/receive messages from each other. That is why I want Tomcat-Enbedded ActiveMQ.